# Allowing a class function to easily be replaced

Tags: c++

I often have a class where I want to allow a functionality to be selected. For example I have a class that has a `GetNextNode()` function which is used like `MyClass::DoIteration(){GetNextNode(); }` . I want to allow the user to select from one of many possible implementations of GetNextNode to determine how the next node to process should be determined. I also want to allow a user of my code to easily provide their own implementation.

So far, the answer is to make `GetNextNode()` virtual and re-implement it subclasses of MyClass...

My problem arises when I have two such interchangeable functions. If I have `Function1()` and `Function2()` which both have N possible implementations, then I would have to provide 2N subclasses to allow the user to pick which pair of these functions to use. Generally, it is much worse (if there are more than 2 such functions).

Note that these functions need access to data inside MyClass.

Is there a "pattern" that I am missing that allows "plugins" like this to be selected?

Comment: Hey David, You should specify whether you need these functions to be interchangeable at compile-time or at run-time. At compile time, this would most likely be done with a Policy class as template argument. At run-time, this would be either a visitor pattern or a composition of interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) Edit: And if you only need compile time variations, the [Policy-based design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) you disovered yourself can be more appropriate.

```
class NextNodeStrategy {
    public:
     virtual int GetNextNode() = 0;
};

class MyClass {
   private:
   NextNodeStrategy &nextNode;
   public:
     void SetNextNodeStrategy(NextNodeStrategy &strategy)
     {
         nextNode = strategy;
     } 
     void DoIteration() 
     {
        nextNode.GetNextNode();
     }
};
```

The strategy might need access to other stuff, so you might need to pass in something to GetNextNode, now that the implementation lives in a separte class, and you might want to provide a default implementation of it (e.g. just have MyClass inherit from NextNodeStrategy , and set `nextNode = this`; in the MyClass constructor.

If you have other things that also can be changed, you make a strategy out of that too, and the 2 can vary independently.

Comment: Yea, the problem is with the "need access to other stuff." The GetNextNode function needs several data and function members of MyClass.

Comment: Then pass them in as arguments, or give them as constructor arguments when you create the NextNodeStrategy objects.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I think what he's looking for is Policy based design, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design.

EDIT:

Example, (obviously doesn't compile, but hopefully you get the idea. You provide a template parameter for IterationPolicy, and it's expected to be a class that provides a getNextNode function. You can provide a default policy and a variety of alternate policies with your class. Also the user can write their own, provided they implement the appropriate interface. Avoids the problems associated with inheritance.

```
template <typename IterationPolicy = DefaultIterationPolicy>
class class X {
    IterationPolicy iterationPolicy;
    void DoIteration() { iterationPolicy.getNextNode(); }
};
```

Comment: Kevin, the problem with this is that the IterationPolicy class will not have access to data of X.

Comment: @David Doria: then add a constructor to X and call something like `iterationPolicy.setHost(this);` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)?

Answer (score 0):

You can offer the different implementations as protected functions.

```
...
protected:
Node GetNextNode_Method1();
Node GetNextNode_Method2();
public:
Node GetNextNode();
...
```

The final class can override GetNextNode() to apply one of the offered alternatives.

Comment: This is quite simple, but actually may work the best for my use case since I need so much access to the MyClass variables and functions. I would just make GetNextNode() pure virtual and force the user to select an implementation by implementing a GetNextNode() that simply calls one of the existing GetNextNode_Method1() type functions, or implementing their own.